# Obtener array desde Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de obtener un array desde firebase pero me aparece error.

```
var lista = arrayListOf<String>()
db.collection("All").document("img").get().addOnSuccessListener {

            lista = it.get("url") as ArrayList<String>
           
        }
```

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.space.victory, PID: 12145
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.ArrayList<kotlin.String> /* = java.util.ArrayList<kotlin.String> */
```

De esta manera obtengo otro tipo de datos

```
db.collection("All").document("home").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Varss.btnurl = it.get("btnurl").toString()
            Varss.alert = it.get("alert") as Boolean
            Varss.version = it.getLong("versionl")!!.toInt()
           
        }
```

Comment: El mensaje es claro, `null` no puede ser convertido a `ArrayList<String>` ni a ningún tipo que no sea nullable. `get("url")` está retornando `null` porque el documento no tiene ningún campo con ese nombre.

Comment: Es cierto, no me había percatado de eso, gracias